# Firefox ignore CSS rule

Tags: css, firefox

I've this CSS fragment

```
.modal-header {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.modal-header BUTTON.close {
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 100%;
}
.modal-header BUTTON.close SPAN {
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 100%;
}
```

I was thinking that so specific rules will be followed by firefox when applying style, but first row, related to `.modal-header` is followed, while other two rules is simply ignored (only here to force the SPAN to be shown in white)

When I open the page, another selector, more generic (`.close`) and preceding the mine in the file, is applied in this situation, so the text into the span is showed in a different color.

I'm generating this CSS using LESS, and in the resulting CSS the code is as copied. But If I open the CSS using Firebug CSS panel, I can't see the rule 2 and 3, only the one.

Of course they're all valid CSS, so, what's the problem?

Please note that IE 11 is rendering it in white color, but it don't apply my `opacity: 100%;` setting

EDIT: I've tried to change cases to lower case but nothing changes.

Edit 2: changed opacity to 1 made entire rule applied and matched thans !

Comment: "Of course they're all valid CSS" — Err, no, they aren't. Try running that code through http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: in css `opacity` should be a value 0.0 - 1.0 (not percentage %) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

Comment: Isn't CSS case sensitive? If it is, I would also try to change BUTTON to button.

Comment: and `SPAN` to `span`

Comment: @Brainfeeder — CSS is case sensitive where it has to be (e.g. for URLs or XML elements names), but HTML element names are not. http://jsbin.com/rivuqo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Quentin okay.. Nice you cleared that out. I however use lower case element names since I thought upper case was/is used in older versions and/or in XML.

Comment: @Brainfeeder — ALL CAPS tag names were a convention back in the 90s. They fell out of favour in the late 90s and XHTML made lower case tag names mandatory. (Subsequent versions of HTML are still case insensitive for tag names).

Comment: @Quentin I rather not have my files scream the element names at me :D good I started coding in the late 90s :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the markup supplied was invalid.

Comment: @Rob I disagree. The mark-up is invalid, indeed, but the poster isn't aware of that and the invalid mark-up is what causes their problem. As such we can only point out that the wrong use of properties leads to their problem, which would then solve their problem.

Comment: @BramVanroy I posted an answer like yours but deleted it because, not only does he have opacity wrong, his rules were written wrong, too, and with others voting to close for other reasons on top of that, I'm just pointing out another in a series of problems with the question. Validation is part of writing markup and should have been done ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, opacity requires a value between 0 and 1. What you need, then, is:

```
.modal-header {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.modal-header BUTTON.close {
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal-header BUTTON.close SPAN {
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

You were probably confused by the good ol' filter-property for IE, in which you could write:

```
/* IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
/* IE 5-7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
```

Note though that this non-standard `filter` property has been deprecated since, and that it is **not** the same as the recently introduced CSS3 property [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).